# Camel Intercept transaction commit

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

We are considering using Camel framework inside one of our integration systems.

Speed processing is one of our main requirements and part of our architecture we are considering a custom caching mechanism. At a high level if some data exists in the cache there is no need to bring it from our storage (say database).

However data consistency is another important requirement. We don't want to have data in the cache that does not reflect the data in the storage. In other words we need our cache being written (updated) only if the storage commit was successful.

So my question is what would be the best way to execute an action (such us updating the cache) only if a transnational route completes. In a normal spring only application I would use either a `TransactionalEventListener` with a `TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT` phase or just a plain non declarative transaction (begin and end of transaction managed inside the code).

Camel frameworks comes instead with so many good to have features that it would be a pity not to use it because this is not possible. I am sure our use case it is not that unusual and hope to hear some advice about how to achieve this.

Thank you in advance,
Julian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [onCompletion](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/oncompletion.html).

> By default the onCompletion will be triggered when the Exchange is complete and regardless if the Exchange completed with success or with an failure (such as an Exception was thrown). You can limit the trigger to only occur onCompleteOnly or by onFailureOnly

Comment: Thanks. I need to check this and come back to you. According to Camel In Action book the UnitOfWork which `onCompletion()` is based. on was introduced "to compensate for the absence of transactional support in other resources.". It should be easy to test by putting a breakpoint in the onCompletion() code of a transacted route and check the database content from a different session. If the content is there it means it works as I want.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I wanted. Excellent solution.